I have a web app deployed to Heroku. What is best way to keep track of versions of the app?
It is just me and a few developers working on a side project, so we do not have formal releases that we are all building towards, but every once and awhile we add new features.
I know in GitHub I can create a new release, but my understanding is I can't make local changes to that if I want to roll back.
I was thinking of just having a file called .version which has the current version in the root and I keep that in sync with GH releases. Or I have heard of tagging commits. What is the best option here?
